# zip multiple jasper reports and send this zip by email

Tags: java, email, jasper-reports

I am currently sending a Jasper Report (invoice) by email with javax mail. It works fine :

```
InputStream reportStream;
reportStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(TEMPLATE_INVOICE); 
JasperDesign jd;

jd = JRXmlLoader.load(reportStream);
JasperReport jr = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jd);
for (Long invoiceId:invoicesId){
    List<Object[]> results = invoiceRepository.findAllByIdInvoice(invoiceId);
    JasperPrint jp = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jr, new HashMap<String,Object>(), dataProvider.getInvoice(results));

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jp, baos);
    mailService.sendMail(baos);
}
```

Now I would like to send a zip containing all my invoices by email.
At each iteration I would add the generated jasper report into a zip file, and then I would send this zip by email.
Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has nothing about jasper report...

You can add one or more file to a zip file using this function (you need to edit that based on your needs).

The actual version get as input parameter a bidimensional array (storing filePath and fileName)...

```
public static byte[] createZipFile(String [][] files) {

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipfile = new ZipOutputStream(bos);
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];        
        String fileName = null;     
        int i = 0;
        try {
            while (i < files.length) {

                String [] singleFile = files[i];                    
                fileName = singleFile[0];
                File f = new File(fileName);                
                if (f.exists())
                {
                    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName);                                
                    zipfile.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(i + "_" + singleFile[1]));
                    int len;
                    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                        zipfile.write(buf, 0, len);
                    }
                    in.close();
                }
                i++;
            }
            zipfile.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }
```